# Python: How to replace some character with a tab

Tags: python, string, replace, tabs

I thought it would be straight forward to replace a character by a tab. I try the following.

```
str1 = "a,b,c,d"
str2 = str1.replace(',','\t')
```

I expect the str2 to be:

```
a     b     c     d
```

Instead I  get:

```
a\tb\tc\td
```

How to replace a charecter with tab?

Comment: I am getting correct result..what version of python you are using?

Comment: It did what you expected. Type `print str2` and you will see.

Comment: Yeah I got the correct result as well
What are you outputting to?

Comment: I see what happened. I didn't use print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`,`s are indeed being replaced by `\t`, but `\t` is only "interpreted" when `str2` is *used* as with printing to screen or writing to file:

```
>>>str1 = "a,b,c,d"
>>>str2 = str1.replace(',','\t')

>>>str2
'a\tb\tc\td'

>>>print str2
a       b       c       d
```